# I can travel through time

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

In certain times of the year I can travel 21 hours in time by crossing this 4 km bridge. Where am I?

Comment: I think the question is too broad, because there are many valid answers

Comment: Made it much more specific. Should be able to find the answer now

Comment: Would [tag:knowledge] or [tag:geography] be appropriate?

Comment: For whoever this may concern, the question has been modified in a way that invalidates some answers; it is not recommended and here's some discussion regarding answers that are made invalid by the change (for example kkm's answer). https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2925/downvoting-answers-made-before-question-edits-clarifications/6653#6653

Comment: @xyldke added those tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible answer but didn't found bridge between two place

> The islands of Big Diomede and Little Diomede

This is because

> Big Diomede is in the easternmost point of Russia and Little Diomede is within the United States' border. They are separated by just two miles (4.8 kilometers) but there is a 20-hour time difference between them.

Comment: Google tells me another time difference. There might also possible be differences due to different way to do rot13(qnlyvtug fnivat)

Comment: Previous versions of the question did mention "certain times of the year".

Comment: You got it! That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, I have been searching the globe around the date line. The 3 hour (45°) of astro time across 5km corresponded to ±89.944⁰ of latitude; no bridges are this close to poles. We deal with the set timezones at _high enough_ latitudes. I found the 2 small islands on both sides of the dateline, but Google Earth showed no bridge; I dropped them off my radar :( The Easternmost TZ in Russia is UTC+12; they don't use DST. +12–21=–9, and the 21h difference is between Russia far East and Alaska far West in H**D**T=UTC-9 Mar to Nov, _certain time of year,_ check. But where's the bridge???

Comment: @kkm the ice bridge only appears during winter

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I was likely wrong about HDT. The E. end of HST is at 169.30°W through the Aleutian Isl., and the E. Diomedes W.most point is at 168.95°W. Google Maps points to the main Alaska TZ, AKST, UTC–9 (–9 is to get the 21h diff. to the E.most Russia TZ UTC+12) _outside_ of DST. So yeah, AKST is in effect through most of winter, except the very end, Mar 13 to the v.eqx., Mar 20±1. I didn't know that the straightlet froze. The whole of the Bering Straight doesn't. I'm very curious to look at your sources; ain't challenging at all, genuinely wondering! :)

Comment: https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/91638/yesterday-and-tomorrow-islands

Comment: https://www.amusingplanet.com/2014/02/diomede-islands-two-islands-split-by-us.html?m=1

Answer (score 8):

You're in

> Malmö, Sweden,

and, if you cross the

> Øresundsbron, a.k.a. Øresund Bridge,

you'll arrive at

> the greater Copenhagen area in Denmark.

> Because of an outdated historical law, Denmark formally observes *mean solar noon* time at 15°E longitude, happening to cross the Danish Bornholm island, which is actually further to the East than even Malmö (≈12°E), where you've started your Westward journey! The exact number had been chosen because 15° corresponds to 360°/24, or one hour. This time is close to CEST, UTC+1, but may be offset from it by as much as a second. Beyond that, the UTC is corrected by adding or removing a leap second.
>
>  Nobody in fact observes this law, and everyone in Denmark uses CEST precisely. It's interesting, however, that Denmark does not have its own atomic clock in sync with the rest of the world…
>
>  Whether it's related to the outdated 19c. law, I don't know.

Comment: Cool answer, upvoted. I was thinking of another **natural** bridge

Comment: Thanks! Another country which has a similar antiquated law is the UK, naming the 0° Greenwich meridian as the mean solar noon reference, but the UK has a Cesium atomic clock at NPL (Natl Physics Lab), and is formally in sync with the world's time. The UK legal system, like the US and other former colonies and unlike the European one, is much more lenient applying laws on the books. And here's a **lifehack** for ya: if your world clock app doesn't offer the UTC (e.g., Android doesn't), use Reykjavik time instead. Iceland is using UTC+0 and has no DST, and thus always in sync with the UTC.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would cause a 21 hour time difference?

Comment: @JacobRaihle check the question edit history, when this answer was posted, the question did not mention 21 hours, only "I can travel through time"

Answer (score 3):

Either

> the Arctic Bridge from Churchill, Manitoba to Murmansk, Russia

or

> the Antarctica Bridge cruise ship

lets you

> cross time zones.

Answer (score 3):

> Bering Strait?

This is because

> it freezes over during the winter allowing you to cross it on foot, thus traversing the International Date Line.

Comment: You are very close to my intended answer. Unfortunately Bering strait is hard to cross. Is there another location in that area that is short and easy to cross? https://angusadventures.com/adventurer-handbook/beringstrait/#:~:text=A%20common%20misconception%20is%20that,large%20channels%20of%20open%20water.

Answer (score 2):

> Time Zone Bridge over Salmon River?

This is because

> The Pacific and Mountain time zones are divided along the Salmon River. Thus, there's actually a place where US 95 crosses the river called Time Zone Bridge. Crossing from one side sends you over into the Pacific Time Zone. Crossing from the other side, you enter Mountain Time..